# tumblr theme text is all bold

Tags: css, themes, tumblr

The theme I'm using is this one [tumblr](https://britishrobertty.tumblr.com/156)

The text post on tumblr.com is both bolded and normal text [boldandnormaljpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75u72.jpg)but this same post shows ALL bolded on the theme [all bolded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2A9x.png). I'm not sure what's overriding it but I've tried everything I've found on the internet but nothing seems to be working.

Can anyone help?

I tried inserting in font - weight : normal ; this one actually changes to the different styles of font on the customisation page, but not on the normal myblog.tumblr.com page [blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFzft.jpg).

NEW IMAGES for @ lharby 6AUG23: [text post on tumblr homepage][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjSNS.png and [HTML of text post on tumblr homepage][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW2Sk.png

Comment: Please share a link where the issue occur, so we can help. :) Did you also check if it occur in a private Browser Tab?

Comment: My guess is that it could either be a non closed tag somewhere, or there is some css override. But either way you will have to share more code, and ideally a link to your blog. At the moment it is impossible to help.

Comment: [link] (https://maziekeen.tumblr.com/post/140653640283/scottisbaes-theme-156-preview-pastebin-or) Hey guys this is the link for the code, sorry I thought I linked it. 
@Patrick I did check for incognito browsing it shows the same.

Comment: @lharby I've shared this now, apologies!

Comment: OK thanks. I am a little confused because I I thought you said your whole theme was showing bold font, but I can see a mixture of normal and bold in the theme. On this page the bold text is wrapped in strong tags the default for these would be that they are bolder than the normal text, but you can also see the corresponding font-weight in the CSS panel on the right (it's saying 700). So is it a particular piece of text on the page you don't want in bold? Or do you want everything to be normal font weight? Screenshot here: https://i.imgur.com/gPAZ4e2.png

Comment: @sia it looks like your font is also completely different from the links you posted. It looks like the CSS is not loading correctly and your default browser font is a bold font. But i cannot see the issue from your screenshot on the mazikeen.tumblr.com page. :/

Comment: @lharby [theme] (https://maziekeen.tumblr.com/post/140653640283/scottisbaes-theme-156-preview-pastebin-or) I'm sorry but you have checked the wrong theme here the provided link has the pastebin code for the theme I'm trying to fix! I just want the posts to have normal and bold texts, currently it's not differentiate as I said in the original post. :(

Comment: @Patrick The link I posted has the pastebin code for the theme I'm using did you check that out? Something is wrong here :((

Comment: So the theme in that post is linked to from here: https://pastebin.com/gXjPgWP0 I have installed the theme here: https://1001100.tumblr.com/ and it looks completely different.

Comment: Can you post a link to your tumblr account, is this someone else's account but is just using the same theme: https://maziekeen.tumblr.com/post/140653640283/scottisbaes-theme-156-preview-pastebin-or 
Ideally you should link to this post https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2A9x.png

Comment: @Iharby It has the theme on the tumblr POST as a PASTEBIN code, and this is what I'm using on my current blog which is [blog] (https://uninvitedawn.tumblr.com/) :(

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I know what is going on. As I mentioned I have made a replica tumblr here: https://1001100.tumblr.com/

And for the first post I have copied the post from your account where you mention everything being in bold.

As you can see from my post it is possible to set all of the font as normal and then add bold or italic styles to specific words, sentences, paragraphs etc.

My suspicion is that you have copied that text into the post from another source? If this is the case it will preserve all of the html and formatting. It looks like every single word or sentence is wrapped in a `<b>` tag which means bold (the other tag is `<strong>`.

[image: Your current Tumblr]

Copy the source text, and then Right Click and choose `Paste and Match Sytle` (this is on Mac, I am not sure what the equivalent is on Windows, but there will be one).

Once you have done that you will be able to select any block of text, add or remove bold, or italic. The upshot is don't just cut and paste from another application, you will always paste the text formatting.

[image: Editor options]

Comment: I really got so happy like of course this is it! But this doesn't work? I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, I've tried doing exactly what you said. But it still shows all bold for the text post. I've added the images where it includes the HTML of that particular post.

Comment: Okay I'm back to say I made a sideblog and it seems to work there but on my main blog? I'm honestly not sure what's happening

Comment: Create a text post and just type some content (don't cut and paste anything). Then make sure you can select text and add bold, italic. Another thing to check is the default format options for your posts, you want Rich Text Editor see: https://i.imgur.com/mSOKZBj.png

Comment: I did this and something seems to be overriding the normal text making it bold if that makes sense?

Comment: So, I would share that post here via a link and using the Inspector I can check for `<b>` or `<strong>` tags. Have you made any modifications to the theme yourself? If so you should post your current version of the theme to a pastebin or similar.

Comment: [New post] (https://uninvitedawn.tumblr.com/post/724908004798087168/sldkjfsd-lksdjfsd-lksjdfsd-lksjdf) Here is the post! I haven't I just took out all the font-weight: ; recently and moved the sidebar to the middle, moved the sidebar title&description&links. The current theme is the one on the link in this comment.

Comment: Yeah everything is wrapped inside a `<b>` tag. I am not really sure how to help you. I don't think it's the theme but it is proving difficult to debug. 
https://i.imgur.com/yXIbSse.png

Comment: It's something really dumb haha I thought I had closed the </b> in the description for the bolded word. But I didn't because I edited it so many times it seems I forgot. So that was it.

Comment: OK if I helped you at all please vote on my answer (I know officially you fixed it, but hopefully I helped).